# On the homology of a graph

Tags: homological-algebra

I am reading Weibel, *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. In chapter one (Exercise 1.1.6.), there is the definition of the homology of a graph, that I can't understand.

> Let $v_1,\ldots,v_V$ be the vertices and $e_1,\ldots,e_E$ the edges of a finite graph. For any ring $R$, let $C$ be the $R$-module chain complex with $C_1$ the free $R$-module on the set of edges, $C_0$ the free $R$-module on the set of vertices, all others $C_n$ the zero $R$-module and the only non-zero differential $d\colon C_1\to C_0$, given by the incidence matrix.

Question: what does it mean that the incidence matrix of the graph works as the differential of the chain complex $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [incidence matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncidenceMatrix.html) of a graph has a row for each vertex, a column for each edge, and a $0$ or $1$ in each entry depending on whether the corresponding vertex is on the corresponding edge.  As an $V\times E$ matrix, it defines a linear transformation from $R^E$ to $R^V$.

This is just a fancy way of saying the differential of an edge is the formal sum of its endpoints.

Comment: Thank you. Forgive my ignorance on $R$-module theory. Is $R^E$ a free $R$-module, as a module over itself, and it is isomorphic to $C_1$ because of the same finite dimension over $R$?

Comment: @bateman: Yes.  Free, finitely-generated $R$-modules might as well be finite-dimensional vector spaces, with the exception that $R$ is not necessarily a field.

Comment: We have $R^n\cong\bigoplus^nR\cong$ free $R$-module on $n$ generators, if $n$ is finite